# How can I convert a buffer array to an object?

Tags: javascript, string, object, buffer

I searched on stackoverflow already, and couldn't find an answer for converting an array buffer to an object; only found answers for a string.

I tried to follow answers using string methods and translate that to object methids but I couldn't figure it out.

This is what I am getting on the client side. I want to convert this back to an object:

```sh
Array [
  123,
  34,
  114,
  101,
  97,
  100,
  34,
  58,
  102,
  97,
  108,
  115,
  101,
  44,
  34,
  116,
  105,
  109,
  101,
  83,
  101,
  110,
  116,
  34,
  58,
  49,
  54,
  52,
  54,
  49,
  55,
  49,
  57,
  50,
  50,
  55,
  48,
  49,
  44,
  34,
  109,
  101,
  115,
  115,
  97,
  103,
  101,
  34,
  58,
  34,
  101,
  116,
  114,
  104,
  34,
  44,
  34,
  117,
  115,
  101,
  114,
  73,
  68,
  34,
  58,
  52,
  55,
  44,
  34,
  99,
  111,
  110,
  116,
  97,
  99,
  116,
  73,
  68,
  34,
  58,
  52,
  55,
  125,
]
```

This function converts from the array to a string:

```js
function arrayBufferToString(buffer) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, arr);
    if (/[\u0080-\uffff]/.test(str)) {
      throw new Error(
        "this string seems to contain (still encoded) multibytes"
      );
    }
    return str;
  }
```

This is what I am getting after running the above function:

```sh
{"read":false,"timeSent":1646174304184,"message":"hjefjhewk","userID":47,"contactID":47}
```

This is the expected output/return value:

```js
{
  read: false,
  timeSent: 1646196262824,
  message: 'Hi',
  userID: 41,
  contactID: 47
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What should your object look like?

Comment: Your function returns a string, yet you claim it's returning an Object.  Also, your input array is invalid; there a comma after its last element.

Comment: But your post says that you get the Object shown above when running the function... You need to modify your function to return an Object instead of a String.

Comment: Hmm, I get its a stringified object that is being returned.

Comment: Have you tried calling JSON.parse() on the string?

Comment: Please provide expected output

Comment: @AlexandrBelan Added it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the issue correctly, you need just parse json string to the object:

```js
const arr = [123,34,114,101,97,100,34,58,102,97,108,115,101,44,34,116,105,109,101,83,101,110,116,34,58,49,54,52,54,49,55,49,57,50,50,55,48,49,44,34,109,101,115,115,97,103,101,34,58,34,101,116,114,104,34,44,34,117,115,101,114,73,68,34,58,52,55,44,34,99,111,110,116,97,99,116,73,68,34,58,52,55,125];

const str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, arr);
const obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```